# Using Python to close Chrome Browser on Win7+

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd

[The specific task to close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bbvp.png)
Ok so i've spent some time researching how to do it and the closest I got was this:

```
os.system("powershell.exe Get-Process chrome | Stop-Process")
```

but then i got this error:

If I run this command from my CMD it works and the chrome window closes with all tabs included.

> 'Stop-Process' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I've tried using the 
'''`os.system(taskkill /IM /F chrome.exe)`''' (with all its options)

Nothing. the best I got was the 'Oh, Snap' page. (the main chrome proccess didn't close).

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you mean `taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe`. The process name is paired with `IM`, not `F`.

Comment: Try taskkill with /T to kill all child processes as well.

Comment: i'm getting "ERROR: Invalid syntax. Value expected for '/IM'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.", also if i place /T at the end. - doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do these:

```
os.system("powershell.exe -command Stop-Process -Name 'chrome'")
```

```
os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
```

Comment: I'm looking to close the specific task as shown in the attached screenshot

Comment: not working pls delete your wrong answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Chrome, but I've tried it on Visual Studio:

```py
import os

cmd =  "taskkill /f /im  Code.exe"
os.system(cmd)
```

It works for me, just replace *Code.exe* to *Chrome.exe*:

```py
import os

cmd =  "taskkill /f /im  Chrome.exe"
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Yeah it works but it keeps the browser open with tabs that show the 'Oh, Snap' page.